# How to update column with unique key constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I've inserted several rows into a table, using duplicates in a column (theId) with a unique key constraint.  I did this by setting IDENTITY_INSERT to off then on.

I tried this same technique to update, since I need to change those dupe values but it isn't working:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable OFF
update mytable set
theId = 5
WHERE mytableId in (40, 41)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON
```

Error:
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'XI_mytale_mytableId_othercolumn_U'.  Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.mytable'.

Any ideas how this can be done with an UPDATE?

Comment: Please explain what you did more thorougly. First two sentences are describing something impossible.

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON; will allow you to manually add values in an Identity Column i.e Auto-increment column. It has nothing to do with Unique Constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing with An Identity Column where you managed to add values manually after Setting SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON; with a Column with Unique Constraint Defined on it. A column with Unique Constraint will never allow you to add duplicate values.
If you do want to be able to add Duplicate values in a column with a unique constraint you can simple drop the unique constraint as why have a unique constraint when you dont have unique values.
You can droo the Unique Constraint using following statement,

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
DROP CONSTRAINT uc_ConstraintName
```

Comment: After looking at it again, you are correct.  There is a composite key involved.